# How to output the second layer of a network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model is trained on digit images (`MNIST dataset`). I am trying to print the output of the second layer of my network - an array of 128 numbers.

After reading a lot of examples - for instance [this](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/?fbclid=IwAR1d32VV8ABGAiKVPQek_90o0YdnziCg6UI1oot1_RWDsXj1YwJM1SHVKIU#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer), [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702455/saving-the-specific-layer-from-within-a-sequential-keras-model?fbclid=IwAR13s1jtYyKB1mToNpvMWljdnenBWUJIAF5pn8rPEQ-Z8tSPCtlp1Z_TmFE).

I did not manage to do this on my own network. Neither of the solutions work of my own algorithm.

Link to Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MLbpWJmq8JZB4_zKongaHP2o3M1FpvAv?fbclid=IwAR20xRz2i6sFS-Nm6Xwfk5hztdXOuxY4tZaDRXxAx3b986HToa9-IaTgASU

I received a lot of different error messages. I tried to handle each of them, but couldn't figure it on my own.

**What am I missing?  How to output the Second layer?**
**If my Shape is `(28,28)` - what should be the type & value of `input_shape`?**

---

Failed trials & Errors for example:

(1)

```
for layer in model.layers:

    get_2nd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],[model.layers[2].output])
    layer_output = get_2nd_layer_output(layer)[0]
    print('\nlayer output: get_2nd_layer_output=, layer=', layer, '\nlayer output: get_2nd_layer_output=', get_2nd_layer_output)
```

> TypeError: inputs should be a list or tuple.

(2)

```
input_shape=(28, 28)
inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functor = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], outputs )   # evaluation function

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = functor([test, 0.])
print('layer_outs',layer_outs)
```

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error
>   while reading resource variable dense_1/bias from Container:
>   localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not
>   found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource:
>   localhost/dense_1/bias)    [[{{node dense_1/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp}}]]

Comment: Links in your question are broken, please add them to have an idea of what you tried

Comment: @ThéoRubenach Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing old keras (before tensorflow 2.0: `import keras`) and new keras (`from tensorflow import keras`).

**Try not to use old keras alongside tensorflow>=2.0** (and not to refer to the old documentation as in your first link), as it is easily confused with the new one (although nothing strictly illogical):

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Model
print(Model.__module__) #outputs 'keras.engine.training'

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
print(Model.__module__) #outputs 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training'
```

Behaviour will be highly unstable mixing those two libraries.

Once this is done, using [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359250/8163053) from what you tried, m being your model, and `my_input_shape` being the shape of your models input ie the shape of one picture (here (28, 28) or (1, 28, 28) if you have batches):

```
from tensorflow import keras as K
my_input_data = np.random.rand(*my_input_shape) 
new_temp_model = K.Model(m.input, m.layers[3].output) #replace 3 with index of desired layer
output_of_3rd_layer = new_temp_model.predict(my_input_data) #this is what you want
```

If you have one image `img` you can directly write `new_temp_model.predict(img)`

Comment: Rubenach what do you mean by 'my_input_shape' ? what should be the value of that var?

Comment: well the shape of input of your model, you even have it in your own code when defining your model: `input_shape=(28, 28)`

Comment: here I use random data, but in your case you should replace `my_input_data` by your own data of course

Comment: What do you mean by 'your own data'? what should be the values inside - training data? test data? should it be only 1 object (image) or a list/array/tuple of objects (images)?
I tried many different combinations of this and none of it worked.
When I set 'input_shape' as you mentioned, I received the error ''AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape''

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. The image you want to use depends on your use case, it has nothing to do with code. If you're still confused, maybe ask a new question on another stackexchange site ?

Answer (score 3):

*(Assuming TF2)*

I think the most straightforward approach would be to name your layers, and then call them with standard input, so your model might look like

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28), name='flatten'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='hidden'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

Then just create an inputs and

```py
my_input = tf.random.normal((1, 28, 28)) # Should be like the standard input to your network
output_of_flatten = model.get_layer('flatten')(my_input)
output_of_hidden = model.get_layer('hidden')(output_of_flatten)
```

`output_of_hidden` is what you are looking for

## Alternative approach

If you are looking for a more general solution, assuming your model is sequential, you can use the `index` keyword of `get_layer` like this

```py
my_input = tf.random.normal((1, 28, 28)) # Should be like the standard input to your network
desired_index = 1  # 1 == second layer

for i in range(desired_index):
    my_input = model.get_layer(index=i)(my_input)
```

At the end of this loop `my_input` should be what you are looking for

Comment: what do you mean by 'my_input = ... # Should be like the standard input to your network' ? what should be the value of that var?

Comment: Any standard input, like what the sequential model expects - if your input is 28x28, you should pass 1x28x28 array for a single example

Comment: Editted my answer to

Comment: How to print the values inside 'output_of_hidden'?
The current result is 'output_of_hidden Tensor("hidden_1/Relu:0", shape=(1, 128), dtype=float32)'.
I tried to use session&eval but I receive errors.

Comment: If in TF2, you should usually call `output_of_hidden.numpy()` and it will convert it to numpy array