# Fine tune Universal Sentence Encoder with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to fine tune [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5) and use the new encoder layer for something else.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import tensorflow_hub as hub

module_url = "universal-sentence-encoder"
model = Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(module_url, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True, name="use"),
    Dropout(0.5, name="dropout"),
    Dense(256, activation="relu", name="dense"),
    Dense(len(y), activation="sigmoid", name="activation")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=256, epochs=30, validation_split=0.25)
```

This worked. Loss went down and accuracy was decent. Now I want to extract just `Universal Sentence Encoder` layer. However, here is what I get.
[image]

1. Do you know how I can fix this `nan` issue? I expected to see encoding of numeric values.
2. Is it only possible to save `tuned_use` layer as a model as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53702886/3128336) recommends? Ideally, I want to save `tuned_use` layer just like `Universal Sentence Encoder` so that I can open and use it exactly the same as `hub.KerasLayer(tuned_use_location, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this will help someone, I ended up solving this by using [universal-sentence-encoder-4](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4) instead of [universal-sentence-encoder-large-5](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5). I spent  quite a lot of time troubleshooting but it was tough as there was no issue with the input data and the model was trained successfully. This might be due to gradient exploding issue but could not add `gradient clipping` or `Leaky ReLU` into the original architecture.